# Is there a vscode settings "macro" for workspace folder in a settings string?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the c++ include guard extension - which is nice. But To make it work really well without a GUID I want to specify the project name in the path. The project name is basically the project workspace folder so I want to do something like this in the json settings file:

```json
 "C/C++ Include Guard.Prefix": "${workspaceFolder}",
```

However this just prints a header guard containing the literal string: "${workspaceFolder}".

Is there a way to get the json settings to print the folder name instead (or any other kind of macros?)

Comment: which extension (URL) do you use and which json file do you edit, you have to ask the developer to add these fields, VSC only does it partially in `tasks.json` and `launch.json`

Comment: sorry - this is the global settings.json for vscode. It is "irrelevant" which extension, because I just want to know there is the language to specfiy the workspace in the settings string?

Comment: looking at the code in the repo the `prefix` config is used but literal and none of the config strings supports variables

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @gnodab IIRC did get something working - i'll dig that out and update tomorrow (if not remind me!)

Comment: @gnodab - added below in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```json
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Auto Include Guard Insertion For New File": true,
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Path Depth": "1",
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Prefix": "TEST_PROJECT_",
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Macro Type":"Filepath",
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Remove Extension": "false",
    "C/C++ Include Guard.Suffix": "_H",
```

So here the header guard starts with my pojects name and then the `Filepath` macro adds the file path to the header guard with path depth of `1`.

E.g. in file `/tmp/my_project/dir1/test.hpp` I would get a header guard like:

`TEST_PROJECT_DIR1_TEST_H`

Having the same prefix (like project name) and path with depth of 1 means that even if the source is at the top level of your repo, you at least get the repo folder (or subfolder) and your project name to add to the uniqueness - as well as the filename itself.